# Avoiding flicker in popover directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, font-awesome, flicker

This simple directive function:

```
function popoverHelp () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            text: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'popoverHelp.html'
    };
```

With this template:

```
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" popover="{{::text}}" popover-placement="top"
popover-title="{{::title}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter"></i>
```

causes flicker when the tooltip is first displayed. The same HTML with static text and no directive does not flicker noticeably.

- Chrome: slight flicker.
- Firefox: popover appears in various positions.
- IE 11: popup flashes on and off.

Adding `ng-cloak` made no difference.

How can I reduce or eliminate the flicker and still use a template?

**Update:**

As requested, I've attempted to create a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ui9jJyCVUDC8EMEa7wO0?p=preview) for this. Unfortunately I've been unable to replicate the issue there, and the popover looks significantly different from the one I see in our production app.

Comment: "flickering" sounds like a Browser-issue. Against which browsers have you tested?

Comment: Do you have a public URL for an example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Please provide a valid JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: I don't know what type of 'flicker' you have, but I had a problem where the template 'flickered' on the wrong place of the screen for a fraction of a second, then displayed on the correct place. I searched long for a solution, and what eventually helped was updating [angular ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: It's possible angular, or the directive template isn't compiled quickly enough and it may cause a flicker, although you have ng-cloak, have you added the rule for ng-cloak - "display: none !important;" to the CSS of the page?

Comment: @CodeBob I did try `ng-cloak` and believe the CSS rule is embedded in angular.js (which is loaded early on). The flickering isn't on page load, it's on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the issue can't be replicated in the Plunk you created, so there is no way for us to see or troubleshoot the problem.  The easiest solution I see to avoiding a flicker would be to use [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

The [Popover](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover) directive they have is simple, and you are already using AngularJS and Bootstrap.  I would look at the dynamicPopover set up, it would be something like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"></i>
```

This should also help with standardizing the look of the popup across browsers.